# Make AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout react to scrolling in RecyclerView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have made a test application with a CollapsingToolbarLayout and a ViewPager. The ViewPager contains three Fragments, one of which is only a simple RecyclerView. My problem is that the CollapsingToolbarLayout (or rather the AppBarLayout) does not expand/contract when the RecyclerView is scrolled, except when the layout is not fully expanded, the RecyclerView is at the top and I scroll downwards. Then the CollapsingToolbarLayout is expanding as well.

**Note: I have uploaded the test application [here](https://github.com/oysteinmyrmo/CollapsibleToolbarNestedScrollViewTest).**

My current layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mm_recipe_activity_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/cake"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There are two types of Fragments used in the ViewPager, one with a simple TextView with lots of text and one with the ViewPager. The Fragments are all wrapped in a `NestedScrollView` to make the scrolling in the ViewPager play nice with the rest of the layout as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31275429/1139324) and other places. Here are the two Fragment layouts, first the one with a simple TextView,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/pink">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and then the one with the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/yellow_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**How can I make the AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout react to scrolling in this RecyclerView?**

Here are some screenshots to show what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Scrolling upwards from the initial position scrolls the RecyclerView itself, but not the AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout. I want scrolling up/down at this point to collapse/expand them normally.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In the first image, the CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed and the RecyclerView is at the top. If I scroll the RecyclerView *down* at this point I start expanding the CollapsingToolbarLayout, as should be expected. If I stop half way through and scroll the RecyclerView *up*, however, I still end up scrolling the RecyclerView upwards, as shown in the third image.

Bonus Question: What is the gray View at the bottom in the third image above? I cannot see that I have added it anywhere. It is also visible at the bottom of the layouts that are just a plain TextView, so it is not because of the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you shouldn't "nest" a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView.

Why?

Because a RecyclerView implements by itself the 'NestedScrollingChild' and 'ScrollingView' interfaces. A NestedScrollView is used to support Views that don't have the Scrolling features, like the LinearLayout which you successfully implemented in the other cases.

Indeed the yellow_fragment.xml works as intended when changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/yellow_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    />
```

Bonus Answer: adding  `android:fillViewport="true"` to your RecyclerView and your NestedScrollViews in green_fragment.xml and pink_fragment.xml will get rid of the grey strip at the bottom of your views. What's this sorcery you might ask:

When a child view inside a Scroll View is smaller than the screen, then `android:fillViewport="true"` is the way to expand that view to fill your screen. Check its effect below:

android:fillViewport = "true" [image: with android:fillViewport]_ vs "false" _[image: without android:fillViewport]

I deleted a paragraph of your TextView's text to highlight the difference even more. Check out Romain Guy's [blog post](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) concerning this function for more info.

**EDIT**: as Krøllebølle mentioned in comments, make sure to have the latest support library version because it may be the reason for the gray stripe to persist even after adding `android:fillViewport="true"` in your view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation. Removing the NestedScrollView around the RecyclerView gives the expected behavior. I am not able to fix the bonus question issue for some reason, even after trying what Romain Guy explained in the blog post. I also tried various combinations of `match_parent`, `wrap_content` and `layout_height="0dp"` together with `layout_weight="1"`. What could I be missing here? I updated the code on Github also.

Comment: That's weird, I can't reproduce your bug. In my Kitkat 4.4.2, I can't see the grey stripe using your updated code. Check if 'android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"' can help in any way!

Comment: Yes, that is weird. When emulating a Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1 the grey bar is there, but on my old Galaxy S3 running Jelly Bean (4.3) everything is ok. Other test emulators running Android 2.3.3 and 4.4.4 are also ok. And a final test on an Xperia Z1 Compact running 5.1.1 *has* they grey bars. So there seems to be some versioning issue at hand. `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical` seemingly does nothing to help this. This problem does not affect my real app, however, just in this test, so it isn't that important for me to fix at this point.

Comment: Updating to support library version 23.2.0 fixes the issue with the gray bar for me. I was using 23.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Its default background color of parent layout. You will always see it until recyclerView/TextView/ViewPager doesn't cover the whole screen. You are having wrap_content as height to both the element. Try to make them match_parent and check the result.

Comment: Are you referring to the gray bare at the bottom? It is also visible in the layouts that just a plain TextView, so it is (probably) not the RecyclerLayout's fault.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: try to check, where ever you have wrap_content change it to match parent for eg viewpager or the containing linearlayout.