# Toolbar not displaying from inside collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nestedscroll"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:fillViewport="true"-->
        <!--android:scrollbars="horizontal"-->
        <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">-->

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <!--</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main_viewpager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The problem:**
1) Toolbar is not visible.
2) Collapsing toolbar doesn't collapse at all. [Solved]
3) Viewpager and FAB also not visible if put inside nestedScrollView. [Solved]

**Extra detail:**
Layout for fragments of Viewpager have Linearlayout as root and inside that have a recyclerview.

Everything seems to be alright as per the code. Unable to understand what is missing. A good explanation of how coordinator layout and collapsing toolbar work together would also indeed help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Toolbar is not visible.

First of all you need define what Toolbar do you want to use in your activity class:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Change existing xml code:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

to:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"  //set initial height
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" //this might be also useful
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

> 2) Collapsing toolbar doesn't collapse at all.

Did your activity using correct theme. Set to your `AppBarLayout`:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

as in this example: [include_list_viewpager.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/043d883a0f38a1a481caeb1db318a36d5c5ff8dd/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml)

> 3) Viewpager and FAB also not visible if put inside nestedScrollView.

There's no reason to do that. Adding these lines:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to `ViewPager` should be enough.

Both of them should be direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Follow this example: http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/

If you're new to Material Design or feel a bit lost with some its behaviours, I highly recommend to check Chris Banes Material Design project `cheesequare`: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/

Hope it will help

Comment: had already figured the 2nd and 3rd. Its the first one that isn't working even after doing this `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I updated my answer. You forgot to set default Toolbar height - `wrap_content` might be in that case be equal to zero. Attribute `actionBarSize` sets Android standard Toolbar size.

Comment: @DarshanMiskin set background to toolbar like `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"`, maybe its not visible because of color :-D

Comment: as from the reference provided by you, figured out that collapsing toolbar isn't necessary when already using a toolbar. Everything's working.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should tell your activity that what toolbar you are using, so in onCreate method you should have:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

your second and third problem should solve together. You should use NestedScrollView as the main layout for fragments inside ViewPager and then inside that, put your LinearLayout or anything else.

Comment: NestedScrollView isn't necessary the property `layout_behavior` is important. check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275277/viewpager-not-appearing-when-using-collapsingtoolbarlayout.   Also, after changing the theme, the collapsing toolbar is not collapsing. Will check your code now.

Comment: after changing the theme, the collapsing toolbar is **NOW** collapsing.